# How to convert new Date() to UTC date using moment JS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to convert the returned value of new Date to UTC format using moment js.

I tried using moment.utc but

```
moment.utc(moment(new Date())).format();
output -> 2020-01-01T04:00:00Z
```

but I want output in this format 
`Thu Jun 04 2020 00:00:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` 
just like what new Date returns but it should be in UTC.

and the other problem is that the return type of format is of

TYPE : STRING I want that the format should be the same but its type should be of date object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UTC is a time standard, not a format.

Comment: `moment().utc().format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ')`. Probably a duplicate of [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1450.4192).

Comment: Thanks @RobG for your reply but the issue here is that the format method returns it as a string but I want it to be returned as Date type.

Comment: I think you're confused about how timezones work. Dates are just a time value, an offset in milliseconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z. They do not have a timezone or any other information, *getTimezoneOffset* returns the system timezone offset, it's not a property of a Date. Local values are calculated for output, they aren't properties of a Date either. Moment.js with timezone support can associate a different timezone with a Date, e.g. moment().utc() returns an object where all values will be UTC by default instead of local.